# CSS align two elements next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at all the other questions on the same topic but none seem to be working. Consider the code-

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="River">
  <p>River</p>
</div>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I am trying to position the switch directly in front of the River label. This would look something like

> RIVER - 'SWITCH'

Any ideas on how I can achieve this

Comment: `display: inline-block;` is what you need

Comment: Why isn't "River" nested in the `label` element if it is intended to be the `label`?

Answer (score 2):

I think u have useless tags and css... Make it simple deleting all the css for switch checkbox and wrap it all on form control div

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF
}
```

```html
<div class="River">
   <div class="form-control">
       <label for="switch-checkbox" class="switch">River</label>
       <input id="switch-checkbox" type="checkbox">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course the checkbox won't stay side-by-side with the `River` because you set `width:100%` to `.River` . I changed your html a little bit for that to work

You have multiple solutions for this ( i don't know how you searched and didn't find a solution )

1. Since you already added float:left yo `switch` , add `float:left` to `.River p`.  See snippet

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.River p {
  float: left;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="River">
  <p>River</p>



  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

2. `display:inline` or `inline-block` on `p` and on `switch`

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  display:inline;
  text-align: center;
}

.River p {
  margin:0;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="River">
  <p>River</p>



  <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

3. Other ways :  using flexbox, grids, tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code

```css
.River {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.switch {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

.river-wrap {
background-color: #00BFFF;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="river-wrap">
  <div class="River">
  <p>River</p>
  </div>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check That,

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.River p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="River">
  <p>River</p>
  <label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone already mentioned it in a comment:

Since "River" is a label, it should be inside your `label` tag. So, if you put it there and wrap `.River` around the `label`, you might not get exactly what you want (guessing based on your rules), but you get the checkbox where you want and can work from there.

```css
.River {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #00BFFF
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="River">

<label class="switch">River
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
</div>
```